# Typescript retrieve Array of ArrayBuffer

Tags: angular, typescript

Sorry if this was already asked, but I couldn't find anything.

I have a rest call to a backend made in Kotlin where I get a list of ByteArray. But I don't know how to handle this in Angular/TypeScript. In a previous version I got only an ArrayBuffer and the function was like this:

```js
downloadDoc(correlationId: string): any {
  const httpOptions = {
    'responseType'  : 'arraybuffer' as 'json'
  };

  return this.httpClient
    .get<ArrayBuffer>('/rest/someUrl/' + correlationId, httpOptions)
    .map(res => {
      if(res.byteLength > 0) {
        return new Blob([res], {type: "image/png"});
      } else {
        return new Blob(['Your document was not found'], {type: "text/plain"});
      }
    });
}
```

And this worked for just an ArrayBuffer but not with List.

I tried with this, but it seems that the images are not rendered

```js
downloadDoc(correlationId: string): Observable<Array<any>> {
  return this.httpClient
    .get<Array<any>>('/rest/someUrl/' + correlationId)
    .map(results =>
      results.map(result => new Blob([result], { type: "image/png" })
    )
  );
}
```

What I'm trying to do is this:

```js
openDocument() {
  this.pngService.downloadDoc(correlationId).subscribe(results => {
    const tab = window.open("", '_blank');
    let data = "";
    results.forEach(function (value) {
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(value);
      data = data.concat("<img src=\"" + fileURL +"\">")
    });
    tab.document.write(data);
  });
}
```

But the generated URL is broken, doesn't load any image in the new tab.

Comment: Have you checked what your fileURLs look like?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if it's good, in the version that worked the result was obviously a bytearray, but in the version that I try to do now that result looks completly different

Comment: What does the result of the get request look like?

Comment: It's a list of long strings, don't know how good it is, it generates blobs from the elements of the list, but definatelly not good.

Comment: It might be that because the request result is now json and not an array buffer anymore that the buffers are now wrong or the body doesn't get parsed correctly anymore. have you tried to base64encode the buffers before sending them from the server?

Comment: I tried encodind, but no success